# requires by babel not resolved by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Babel-loader adds "require" statements due to "useBuiltIns: usage ", webpack transcribes them into import statements but doesn't resolve them.
Resulting in the following inside bundle.js and an error in the browser:

```
import "core-js/modules/es6.function.name"
```

I am using script-laoder to bundle them, which evals each file as string.
I just don't know how to tell webpack/script-loader to remove the import statements and include the modules in the bundle.

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  entry: {
    website: [
      jsPath("babel-helpers.js"), // generated from babeL
      jsPath('testfolder/test.js'),
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [ //executed bottom to top!
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [ 'script-loader' ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.ajs$/,
                exclude: [/\.min\.js$/, /node_modules/],
                use: {
                    loader: 'uglify-es-loader',
                    options: {
                      //parse: {},
                      //compress: {},
                      //mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
                    }
                }
              },
              { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: [/\.min\.js$/, /node_modules/, /babel-helpers/], // exclude babel-helpers or error.
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                // options: { //uses config from .babelrc file when not specified here.
                //   presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                // }
              },
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/\.min\.js$/, /node_modules/, /babel-helpers/],
                loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                options: {
                  multiple: [
                     { search: 'process.env.NODE_ENV', replace: JSON.stringify('production') },
                  ]
                }
              }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, jsFolder),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'add'
  }
};
```

package.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.2.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"script-loader": "^0.7.2",
"string-replace-loader": "^2.2.0",
"uglify-es-loader": "^3.0.4",
"webpack": "^4.36.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/env",
          {
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "targets": 
            {
              "edge": "17",
              "firefox": "60",
              "chrome": "67",
              "safari": "11.1",
              "ie": "11"
            }
          }
      ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers"
  ]
  }
```